# Содержимое указателя

Tags: c++, указатели

Немного запутался:

1. `int *a=new int;` - выделение памяти из кучи.
2. `a`  - адрес начала выделенных 6 байт
3. `*a` - значение которое находится по адресу `a`

**Неправильная запись в переменную**

`a=13; // 3) произошла запись не значения а адреса, то есть теперь адрес равен 13, а не какому-нибудь 0x12345678. 4)Теперь нельзя освободить часть кучи`

**Правильная запись в переменную**

```
*a=13; // Разименнование указателя
```

Пронумеровал моменты, которые меня интересуют. Напишите какое из утверждений не верно, если такие есть

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71201/discussion-on-question-by----).

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, только одно - *адрес начала выделенных 6 байт* - не то чтобы это невозможно, но пока даже не слышал об 6-байтных `int`.

А так - все верно.

Comment: Перепутал просто

Answer (score 1):

> `int *a=new int;` - выделение памяти из кучи.

В общем случае - да. Но, например, `operator new` может быть перегружен и тогда всё будет зависеть от его работы.

> `a` - адрес начала выделенных 6 байт

В общем случае - нет. Например, если выделяется массив объектов `non-pod` типа, то `new-expression` может запросить больше памяти, и в начале выделенной памяти поместить количество созданных объектов в выделенной памяти, чтобы потом `delete-expression` мог вызвать необходимое количество деструкторов для созданных объектов. При этом `new-expression` вернет указатель уже не на начало выделенной памяти, а на ту память, в которой начинаются Ваши объекты, которыми Вы можете законно оперировать.

> `a=13;` // 3) произошла запись не значения а адреса, то есть теперь адрес равен 13, а не какому-нибудь 0x12345678.

При таком коде возникнет ошибка компиляции, т.к. неявное преобразование из int в указательный тип запрещено. Но оно разрешено для литерала 0, поэтому код `a = 0;` собрался бы без проблем и да, значение бы стало равно нулю. При этом внутреннее представление указателя определяется реализацией и не обязано быть нулем. Однако, программе об этом заботиться не нужно, все необходимые преобразования из внутреннего представления в численный ноль и наоборот будут сделаны без Вашего участия.

> 4)Теперь нельзя освободить часть кучи

Если больше нигде нет сохраненного адреса, то да.